# Threading when excluding subprocess

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I wrote a program that catches keyboard events on tetris, which was opened via a subprocess. no when i only want to catch events without opening Tetris my keyboard handler (pyHook) won't catch the events:

```
# open Tetris
#Tetris = subprocess.Popen (["C:\\Program Files (x86)\Tetris\Tetris.exe"])
#start game by sending "F2" key
#for hwnd in get_hwnds_for_pid (Tetris.pid):
    #win32gui.PostMessage (hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_F2, 0)

keyH = KeyHandler()
ToneT = ToneTimer()

keyH.setDaemon(True)
ToneT.setDaemon(True)

keyH.start()
ToneT.start()
```

this worked fine when using another subprocess but i do not know why this is stuck now. KeyHandler won't pick up the keys.

```
class KeyHandler(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
        # watch for all keyboard events
        KeyHandler.hm.KeyDown = self.OnKeyboardCharEvent
        # set the hook
        KeyHandler.hm.HookKeyboard()
        # activate message pipeline
        print "keyboardhooked"
        pythoncom.PumpMessages()
        print "thisshouldnotbeprinted"
```

all but the last statement gets printed, but evoked keys are not printed, but instead when i press a key the app freezes (I have a function to catch events that works fine with the subprocess included...)

I guess there is something wrong with the threading when leaving out the subprocess.

I found out that if I switch to another GUI window before pressing a key, and then press a key, keys get accepted and keyevents printed.

More precise info: This probably has to do with running the script inside of OpenSesame (experimental software) as somehow pyhook does not retrieve keyboard responses from his window / windows in general but only from gui windows?! Thus I might need to seek an alternative for pyhook here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working due to Qt bypassing the windows message loop -- pyHook relies on the message loop to function.

> Modern graphical interface frameworks, such as Windows Forms, Windows
>   Presentation Foundation, MFC, Delphi, **Qt** and others do not
>   typically require applications to directly access the Windows message
>   loop, but instead automatically route events such as key presses and
>   mouse clicks to their appropriate handlers as defined within the
>   framework.

From [Message Loop in MS Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows)

Comment: it is called last. it is the last statement in the run method after starting the keyhandler thread. the problem it that it is not looking at the events of the current thread but only of another gui window. (see my edit)

Comment: Did you try testing it after moving PumpMessages outside of the thread?  It worked for me.

Comment: yes i did, no changes. it works if you have any gui window active, but somehow not while using just the script. as mentioned, this works perfectly fine when in open the tetris window :(

Comment: When you say "just using the script", what does that mean?  Running it in the interpreter?

Comment: I run this within [open sesame](http://osdoc.cogsci.nl/) (experimental software) as an inline script

Comment: this seems to be the problem but how to fix it? ;)

Comment: i found a workaround with minimizing the window instantly that does the job, but is not always a solutio I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The run method needs to have a loop. The thread ends once it leaves the run method.

```
class KeyHandler(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.running = True
    # end

    def run(self):

        while self.running:
            # watch for all keyboard events
            KeyHandler.hm.KeyDown = self.OnKeyboardCharEvent
            # set the hook
            KeyHandler.hm.HookKeyboard()
            # activate message pipeline
            print "keyboardhooked"
            pythoncom.PumpMessages()
            print "thisshouldnotbeprinted"

    # end run
```

or You don't have to subclass it at all.

```
def catch_key(keyboard):
    # watch for all keyboard events
    KeyHandler.hm.KeyDown = keyboard.OnKeyboardCharEvent
    # set the hook
    KeyHandler.hm.HookKeyboard()
    # activate message pipeline
    print "keyboardhooked"
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
    print "thisshouldnotbeprinted"

thread = threading.Thread(target=catch_key, args=(Keyboard()))
thread.start()
# Remember to use thread.join() to safely close the thread.
```

Comment: I think that is not the solution, it is OK as PumpMessages() continues to release messages unless explicitly closesed by ctypes.windll.user32.PostQuitMessage(0). Thus, it is OK that "thisshouldnotbeprinted" is not printed. I reedited my question, I get response while I open another GUI Window, thus, this might be due to restriction of [pyHook](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=Main_Page)?

Comment: @refuzee Ok so PumpMessages() has the loop. There seems to be something you have to do with pyHook. This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562993/python-threading-with-pyhook